# To check the following funtion is distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

The given function is $F(x)$=$\frac{1}{\pi}tan^{-1}x$: $-\infty <x<\infty$
As we know that for the distribution function $lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$ but for the given function I am getting $lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}tan^{-1}x=-\frac{1}{2}$ so according to me this is not a distribution function of any random variable but the book I am referring they have given that it is a distribution function, where I am doing mistake?

Comment: You are correct. See [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) with $x_0=0$ and $\gamma=1$.

Comment: $F(x)+1/2$ is a distribution function.